# Switch Ringing Mode from Vibration to Normal during a call

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I can`t switch the AudionManager Ringer mode to a normal mode during an incoming call.
The problem is that if the vibration mode was active before the incoming call, the actual switching to normal mode occurs and phone not playing ringtone, and continues to vibrates only. The ringer volume also successfully increased, but phone not playing ringtone. I tested it on the Nexus 5.
An interesting fact is that if the RINGER_MODE_NORMAL was active before the incoming call - the switch from normal mode to vibration mode works well - the phone stops playing ringtone, and only vibrate.
No any errors or strange messages in LogCat - the phone just vibrates.
Scenario:
1. Phone in vibration mode
2. Incoming call
3. audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)
4. Vibration icon disappears
5. The phone continues to vibrate only (its problem)

Docs for AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL says "It will be audible if the volume before changing out of this mode was audible. It will vibrate if the vibrate setting is on."
And I tryed to set max volume before changing mode - still doesn`t work.

Is it possible, or its some security limitations? Search did not give me the results.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Billda no. I suppose, it's just impossible.

Answer (score 0):

instead of RINGER_MODE_NORMAL use this, I hope it works for you

```
 am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 //when u want to go on ringer mode
 am.setRingerMode(2);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because 2 it's just the same as RINGER_MODE_NORMAL. There is no difference.